# 2 tr:selectOneChoice ValueChangeListeners call the same action method

Tags: jsp, jsf, facelets, jspx, trinidad

I have 2 tr:selectOneChoice components and each has its own valueChangeListener method. The issue is that when changing the value from the dropdown box 1, it will call the action method 1, which is expected.

But when changing the value from dropdown box 2, it will call the action method 1 and action method 2 in order, which is really weird, it should not call the action method 1 at all. The worst part is that, even if I click on different buttons that I have on the same page, they both invoke both action methods in order as well, which is really bad and I have no ideas how to explain it.

I am using MyFaces, Facelets, Trinidad. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `valueChangeListener` will only be invoked when the submitted value is different from the value as returned by the associated getter during validations phase. One of most common causes for your particular problem is that the bean is request scoped and that the initial value isn't been preserved.

If you was using JSF 2.0, you need to put the bean in `view` scope so that it will be retained in direct subsequent requests on the same view. But when you're still on 1.x, then the easiest fix is to put the bean in the session scope. However, this has caveats as well; when an user opens the same page in different tabs/windows in the same browser session, they will interfere with each other. Best solution is then to use Tomahawk's [`<t:saveState>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_saveState.html). Put the following line somewhere in the page with the form with the dropdowns:

```
<t:saveState value="#{bean}" />
```

This way the bean will be retained in subsequent requests on the same view, which acts like the new JSF 2.0 `view` scope.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your quick response. I understand why my value changed listener methods being called, but it should just call its own method, and certainly not other value changed listener methods in the same order. It is even worst when I click on my buttons (which have nothing to do with those value change listeners) on the same page, these buttons invoke both of my value changed listener methods and its own action method in the same order. I am using JSF 1.x and thank you very much.

Comment: As said, the valuechangelistener method is **only** invoked when the submitted value differs from the initial value. You need to ensure that the initial value doesn't change in the subsequent request. It's not like Javascript or so.